# Org-mode: HTML Attributes on begin_center environment

Tags: org-mode

Typically, it is possible to add html attributes to the `#+begin_xxx` tags,
e.g.:

```
#+attr_html: :style display:flex;
#+begin_div
Testing...
#+end_div
```

However, when I try to do this with `#+begin_center`, no such changes are
applied, e.g.:

```
#+attr_html: :style display:flex;
#+begin_center
Testing...
#+end_center
```

Yields the HTML:

```
<div class="org-center">
<p>
Testing&#x2026;
</p>
</div>
```

I assume this is because center is used specially somehow, but is it possible to add these attributes to that environment anyways?

Comment: You will have to override the built-in function that processes center blocks (`org-html-center-block`) which does not look at any atrributes and replace it with one that does. It's a one-line function so it should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that processes center blocks in the HTML exporter is `org-html-center-block`. Here it is in its entirety:

```el
(defun org-html-center-block (_center-block contents _info)
  "Transcode a CENTER-BLOCK element from Org to HTML.
CONTENTS holds the contents of the block.  INFO is a plist
holding contextual information."
  (format "<div class=\"org-center\">\n%s</div>" contents))
```

As you can see, it doesn't do anything with attributes: it just wraps a `div` of class `org-center` around the contents and that's it.

You will need to override this function in order to add attributes. Here's a slightly enhanced Org mode file that's based on your example. It adds a `noexport` `Code` section that contains an elisp source code block with a modified `org-html-center-block` function:

```el
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Foo

#+attr_html: :style display:flex;
#+begin_div
Testing...
#+end_div

However, when I try to do this with #+begin_center,
no such changes are applied, e.g.:

#+attr_html: :style display:flex;
#+begin_center
Testing...
#+end_center

* Code                                                         :noexport:
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun org-html-center-block (center-block contents _info)
    "Transcode a CENTER-BLOCK element from Org to HTML.
  CONTENTS holds the contents of the block.  INFO is a plist
  holding contextual information."
    (let* ((attributes (org-export-read-attribute :attr_html center-block))
           (attrs (org-html--make-attribute-string attributes)))
      (format "<div class=\"org-center\"%s>\n%s</div>"
              (if (org-string-nw-p attrs)
                  (concat " " attrs)
                "")
              contents)))
#+end_src
```

If you press `C-c C-c` on the code block, the modified function will override the original one. You can then export with `C-c C-e h h` and look at the HTML file.

The function makes use of the `center-block` argument and extracts the `:attr_html` value (which was initialized from the `#+ATTR_HTML` that was attached to the center block in the file). The value is a list of zero or more elements (in this case just one: the `:style` attribute with value `display:flex;`). The list is massaged and converted into a string (in this case a string like this: `"style=\"display;flex;\""`) which is then given to `format` to produce the final form:

```html
<div class="org-center" style="display:flex;">
<p>
Testing&#x2026;
</p>
</div>
```

The function can accommodate multiple attributes (or no attributes).

If after you've done the export, you decide that you want to revert to the original function after all, you can restart Emacs or do `M-x load-library ox-html`. OTOH, if you decide you want to have the new function in force permanently, you can add it to your init file, although you'll have to make sure to evaluate the `defun` *after* the original function has been defined, so that the original will be overridden. You can do that with an `eval-after-load` form like this:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ox-html
  (defun org-html-center-block (center-block contents _info)
     ...)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very thorough answer!